# How to check if a key exists in a MemoryCache

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I need to check if a key is present in a MemoryCache. However there is no Keys collection or something similar available.

I do not need the object associated with the key only a true or false if a certain key is present.

I know I can try a .Get(key) but I do not need the object. Is this the only way?

Comment: Post your code, so everyone can help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `bool Contains(string key, string regionName)` method.

**MSDN**:

> Determines whether a cache entry exists in the cache.
>   Return Value Type: System.Boolean true if the cache contains a cache
>   entry whose key matches key; otherwise, false.
>   <sub>[MemoryCache.Contains Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.contains.aspx), *MSDN*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I could have missed that!

Comment: @oakio, Can i check cache not from code? From browser etc.

Comment: @user2167382 No, because it is server-side cache

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the cache is not Null & post that check if the key exists or not (by using .Contains method).

```
if (myCache != null && myCache.Contains("keyName") && myCache.Get("keyName") != null)
{
    myDS = (DataSet)myCache.Get("keyName");
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but `MemoryCache` cannot contain a `null` value. *The MemoryCache class does not allow null as a value in the cache. Any attempt to add or change a cache entry with a value of null will fail.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: @nico the same documentation says that the Get() method returns: _A reference to the cache entry that is identified by key, if the entry exists; **otherwise, null**._ [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.get?view=netframework-4.7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.get?view=netframework-4.7.1)